# How to use Kafka connect to transmit data to Kafka broker in another machine?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to use Kafka connect in Confluent platform 3.2.1 and everything works fine in my local env. Then I encountered this problem when I try to use Kafka source connector to send data to another machine.

I deploy Kafka JDBC source connector in machine A and trying to capture database A. Then I deploy a Kafka borker B(along with zk, schema registry) in machine B. The source connector cannot send data to broker B and throws the following exception:

```
[2017-05-19 16:37:22,709] ERROR Failed to commit offsets for WorkerSourceTask{id=test-multi-0} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:112)
[2017-05-19 16:38:27,711] ERROR Failed to flush WorkerSourceTask{id=test-multi-0}, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 3 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:304)
```

I tried config the server.properties in broker B like this:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

and leave the advertised.listeners setting commented.
Then I use

```
bootstrap.servers=192.168.19.234:9092
```

in my source connector where 192.168.19.234 is the IP of machine B. Machine A and B are in the same subnet.

I suspect this has something to do with my server.properties.

How should I config to get the things done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Case closed: it's due to the op closed the 9092 port.